# String not recognized C# Web Form

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, web-services

I'm making a new web service that translates works from a short dictionary of abbreviations in the form of a .csv file.

The code for the web form

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO;


public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> _dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"C:/dictionary.csv")))
        {
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                string[] tokens = reader.ReadLine().Split(';');
                _dictionary[tokens[0]] = tokens[1];
            }
        }
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        localhost.Service obj = new localhost.Service();
        TextBox1.Text = (obj.Translate());
    }
}
```

The code for the Web Service

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.IO;
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class Service : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    public Service() { }
    [WebMethod]
    public string Translate(string input)
    {
        string output;
        if (_dictionary.TryGetValue(input, out output))
            return output;

        throw new Exception("Invalid input, please try again.");
    }
}
```

I'm getting Error: 'The name '_dictionary' does not exist in the current context' even though I have created the string and made the reference. Any suggestions why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `_dictionary` is a member of the `_Default` class and not the `Service` class.

As Marvin Smit suggests in the comment, move your `_dictionary` declaration to the `Service` class, move your initialization code currently in `_Default's` `Page_Load` to a constructor on `Service`.

Comment: move the dictionary & initialization code to your service, instead of  the page_load.